# extjs 4 - stop controller from attempting to load the view js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Sorry if that's a real noob question but just doesn't seem obvious in the docs.

I'm creating a controller and a view for an app.

My Controller and View classes are already defined. If i manually instantiate the view (in the init method or whatever for instance) then it all works fine.

But if I add the view name in the views array config of the controller, ext 4 tries to load it again from the server, even though it's already defined.

e.g.

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.TestView', {

    /* some code */

});

Ext.define('Admin.controller.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views : [
        'TestView'      // <- this causes ext to try to load the view, even though it's already an existing type
    ]

    /* some code  */

});
```

What do I need to do to stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The views, stores, and models configs will automatically create an instance of that class. To stop this from happening, the only way is to not use them. The only benefit to using this is that it creates a getter to access that instance. I am trying to improve this but don't want to break this functionality.

For models it's no big deal. For stores, if you need a global store that is already present it's not that big of a deal.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My problem is not in the instanciation itself, it's that extjs will try to load the view definition again from the server (I can see the request in firebug), even though Admin.view.TestView is already an existing class..